# Angular routerLink appends route instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, angular, router

I have the following route configuration in my Angular app

```
...
{ path: 'item/new', component: ItemDetailsComponent, pathMatch: 'full', data: { new: true } },
{ path: 'item/:id/:action', component: ItemDetailsComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
...
```

were **:action** can be either "view" or "edit". All three possible paths do work when I enter them directly into the browser. However, the router links within the item-template do not:

```
<div routerLink="['/item', id, 'edit']">Test</div>
```

"id" is set within the component, so thats likely not the problem. The browser console error indicates that the url is somehow appended:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'item/2/view/%5B'/item',%20id,%20'edit'%5D'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'item/2/view/%5B'/item',%20id,%20'edit'%5D'
```

Since the router link does start with a slash, I expected this to work.

Comment: Try with `[routerLink]` instead of `routerLink`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u should use

```
<div [routerLink]="['/item', id, 'edit']">Test</div>
```

or

```
<div routerLink="/item/{{id}}/edit">Test</div>
```